# Android app crashes since shared library cannot fit in /system

Tags: android, android-ndk, dynamic-linking

I have a shared library that I build with the Android NDK, which ends up being 80MB (yes, huge!).  I absolutely cannot shrink it down in size.  The problem is, when the Android application is being installed the shared library cannot fit in /system on my phone because only 300K is free.  So when the application tries to run, it crashes with a SIGBUS error since not all of the library is there. Freeing any more space in /system would be near impossible without possibly breaking a lot of things.

So, I was wondering if there is another way to link to this library by putting it on another partition like /data which has 150MB free.  Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: +1  Wow .. I'm impressed.  If that's all code (versus some other kind of resource) I'm seriously impressed ... not easy to do, frankly.

Comment: it's wireshark :)  their "dissector" code for parsing packets is huge

Comment: I've heard of the tool, but had no idea it would/could be the large.  Frankly, I'm a bit dumbfounded at how they filled 80 megs on TCP / IP / Socket / Frame based coding.  I do allot of communication stuff myself ... 80 is just allot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install .so files also to `/data/data/YOURPACKAGE/lib/`

You'll have to research how to do it, though, since I don't have experience on it.

Edit: take a look at this post: http://www.aton.com/android-native-libraries-for-java-applications/

Comment: interesting, I see my libraries there now! it seems as though everything from the Android source code in libs/armeabi/* gets installed here.  So, my entire library is there and it fits.  The interesting thing is, when I try to do System.LoadLibrary(blah) it then tries to copy it to /system/lib and that's where it fails

Comment: So, apparently this is automatically done, and they will load directly from here as long as I do not also install them in /system/lib (only possible with a rooted phone)

Answer (score 0):

> So, I was wondering if there is another way to link to this library by putting it on another partition like /data which has 150MB free.

You are welcome to write your own firmware.

Otherwise, you cannot change what happens with this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't entirely believe this, as for example Linux has an ld.so.conf file to add extra library paths. Although, android does not have this or ldconfig. There may also be system variables to add library paths.

Comment: @gnychis: On a rooted phone, there could possibly be solutions -- you can't change any of the stuff in your comment without superuser privileges on Linux, either. Since you did not specify otherwise, I am assuming that you are trying to do this as a standard SDK app to be deployed to arbitrary devices. For an SDK application to be deployed to arbitrary devices, I can state with absolute certainty that what you seek is impossible.